# Printing outcomes for rolling 4 dice 10,000 times

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dice

The program I'm writing simulates rolling 4 dice and adds the result from each together into a "Total" column. I'm trying to print the outcomes for 10,000 dice rolls but for some reason the value of each dice drops to 0.0 somewhere in the program and it continues like this until the end. Could anyone tell me what's going wrong here and how to fix it? Thanks :)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


np.random.seed(101)
four_dice = np.zeros([pow(10,4),5]) # 10,000 rows, 5 columns
n = 0
outcomes = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in outcomes:
    for j in outcomes:
        for k in outcomes:
            for l in outcomes:
                four_dice[n,:] = [i,j,k,l,i+j+k+l]
                n +=1
four_dice_df = pd.DataFrame(four_dice,columns=('1','2','3','4','Total')) 
print(four_dice_df) #print the table
```

**OUTPUT**

```
        1    2    3    4  Total
0     1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0    4.0
1     1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0    5.0
2     1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0    6.0
3     1.0  1.0  1.0  4.0    7.0
4     1.0  1.0  1.0  5.0    8.0
...   ...  ...  ...  ...    ...
9995  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0
9996  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0
9997  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0
9998  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0
9999  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0

[10000 rows x 5 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

You ran out of dice combinations.  You made your table 10^4 rows long, but there are only 6^4 combinations.  Any row from 1296 through 9999 will be 0, because that's the initialized value.

To fix this, cut your table at the proper value: pow(6, 4)

---

Response to OP comment:

Of course you can write a loop.  In this case, the controlling factor should be the number of results you want.  Then you generate permutations to fulfill your needs.  The Pythonic way to do this is to use the `itertools` package: `permutations` will give you the rolls in order; `cycle` will repeat the sequence until you quit asking.

However, the more obvious way for your current programming is perhaps to simply count in base 6:

```
digits = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

for i in range(10000):
    # Record your digits in the data frame
    ...
    # Add one for the next iteration; roll over if the die is already 6
    for idx, die in enumerate(digits):
        if die < 6:
            digits[idx] += 1
            break
        else:   # Reset die to 1 and continue to next die
            digits[idx] = 1
```

This will increment the dice, left to right, until you either have one that doesn't need a reset to 1, or run out of dice.

Another possibility is to copy any of the many base-conversion functions available on line.  Convert your iteration counter `i` to base 6, take the lowest 4 digits (quantity of dice), and add 1 to each digit.

Comment: Say after max combinations have been reached at row 1296 and I wanted the entire rolling process to begin again in the next row, would implementing some sort of loop then allow me to reach 10,000 outcomes?

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for what you want?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,7,size=(10000,4)),columns = [1,2,3,4])
df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: `randint(1,6)` wouldn't yield `6`. I think you mean `randint(1,7,...)`.